# Fetching data using Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have searched quite a lot on the internet but can't find what I'm looking for.

I have this model where it could be a lot of users. So I have an entity called `User`. The user has an `NSSet` of records. And I want to fetch records from given user. I'm trying to do it like this but it still returns records from all users.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = _backgroundContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Record"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@)",date];
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"User = %@",currentUser];

NSPredicate *predicates = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicate,predicate1, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicates];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

I know it shouldn't be hard, but I can't find what it is, and I'm hoping some of you could help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

As I said I have an entity `User` which has:

```
NSString name,
int age,
NSSet records, ...
```

`Record` has its own properties such as:

```
NSDate date,
NSString name,
NSString event, 
...
```

I want to form a fetch request to get records just from specific user.  And I don't know how to do it, because I'm getting all of the records from every user.

records has a To-Many relationship. I can get records like currentUser.records, but i can't get user using record.User.

Comment: Could you be little brief I mean are you using any relationships? If yes then please provide little brief.

Comment: Checkout MagicalRecord (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). It'll make working with Core Data a whole lot easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicates];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

After setting the compound predicate, you overwrite it with the predicate for `date` alone. You probably want to delete the second line.

*EDIT:* The fetch request requires that you have defined a inverse relationship `user` from `Record` to `User` and use the exact name of this relationship in the predicate.

An alternative solution is to use the "forward" relationship from `User` to `Record` and filter the result:

```
NSSet *records = [currentUser.records filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicates];
```

or, if you prefer an array

```
NSArray *records = [[currentUser.records allObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicates];
```

Comment: well stupid me! Thanks for this, but that doesn't solve my problem :( I get an error "keypath User not found in entity".

Comment: @Lukas: What is the relationship from `Record` to `User` called? Perhaps `user` (lowercase)? If that does not help, please show use the definition of `Record` entity.

Comment: see my edit, i can't get user like record.User, i can only get records by using currentUser.records. I can run a loop in this set but it seems nasty. So i'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: @Lukas: You have to define `user` as relationship to from `Record` to `User` (inverse relationship to `records`). Then a predicate `"user = %@", currentUser` should work.

Comment: @Lukas: Just a note: `currentUser.records` is a sensible alternative. You can filter that using `filteredSetUsingPredicate:` - no need for a loop!

Comment: well that's another good suggestion, that would fit my needs i think!

Comment: could you post this as an answer, so i could accept it? Because that's what i needed!

Comment: @Lukas: I have added the suggestion to my answer. Do you think you can accept it like this?

Comment: sure! Thanks again for the superb help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your model looks roughly like this, i.e. the records relationship has an inverse relationship called user:

[image: User-Record model]

It's importantant that this relationship is an inverse relationship because otherwise Core Data will not automatically maintain it. You can then query all Records for the given User on/after the given date like this:

```c
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Record"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user = %@ AND (date >= %@)", currentUser, date];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *records = [_backgroundContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSLog(@"records: %@", records);
```

I've rewritten your code to be more compact, but the important change is that this will create the query in just one go.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin R said, you're replacing your predicate.
As he also mention, the user property should be lowercase, as I'm pretty sure that core-data enforces this. It should give you an error if you try creating a relationship with an upper case letter, so try

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user = %@",currentUser];
```

instead. Obviously if your model doesn't define a property for user then that won't work either and you'll need to change it to whatever your model actually has, but that should work otherwise.

**Edit:**

Try adding an inverse relationship in your model. So your structure would look like :

**user**

```
NSString name,
int age,
NSSet records, ...
```

**Record**

```
NSDate date,
NSString name,
NSString event, 
User user,
...
```

Then every time you create a new record, as well as adding the record to the users record set, set the user on the record object as well. This will make fetching the records a lot easier, and also it allows core data to keep data integrity:

```
"You should typically model relationships in both directions, and specify the inverse 
relationships appropriately. Core Data uses this information to ensure the consistency of the 
object graph if a change is made"
```

[(Core Data programming guide)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

Once this is setup, you should easily be able to get the records user by simply calling `record.user`

If you need multiple users for multiple records, then simply setup the relationship as a to-many relationship, and change the `User user` property to `NSSet user`.

If you don't want to change your models this much, then I'm a bit confused with your question. You say you want to get the records for a given user? If so, then why don't you simply call `user.records` as you have that relationship already defined? There's no need for an entire fetch request for that, let core data manage that one for you.

If you then want to filter the resulting Records based on the date, you can apply a predicate to the resulting array yourself, again without the need for a fetch request.

Comment: well that doesn't work, but thanks for trying to help! As i said i can't get user from record.user :/ It can only work the other way around like currentUser.records, which would return all records of this user.

Comment: You just need to add an inverse relationship (apple recommends this for data consistency) so on you record model, add either a user relationship (one-to-many), or users (many-to-many). Then when you create a record, just set the user or add a user and you should be able to do what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I've searched! I just needed to form a predicate using this

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = %@",delegate.currentUser];
```

**EDIT**

Well it seems that i was wrong :/ That only seemed to work.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. But you should double-check your solution, because to mr it seems to be something different from your question.

Comment: @MartinR Your're right! That only seemed to work because I've teste only with couple of records. Sad :/